# Getting 403 Forbidden error on BigCommerce Cart API on Postman

Tags: postman, http-status-code-403, bigcommerce

Instead of returning CartEntity I am getting 403 errors. I have the correct authentication.

Comment: Have you set the client ID and the access token correctly? Can you post a screenshot of your request and response without the credentials?

Comment: what does ur request look like